# In python program need to understand the print statement and float usage and What is the use of format function?

Tags: python

```
num1=1.0

num2=5.0

sum=float (num1)+float (num2)

print ('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format (num1,num2,sum))
```

In this program, can u please explain the print statement? What is the use of format function? And what is that `{0},{1},{2}`?

And in `Sum` statement already the values of `num1` and `num2` are in float why we must again use float like float (num)?

Comment: `format` will replace the parameters in the order given by `{0} {1} ...`. You can try with `print ('{2} is the sum of {0} and {1}'.format (num1,num2,sum))`

Answer (score 1):

This program return same result

```
num1 = 1.
num2 = 5. 
sum = num1 + num2
print ('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format (num1, num2, sum))
>>> The sum of 1.0 and 5.0 is 6.0
```

so, You do not have to do wrap num1, num2. cuz (num1 + num2) is already float, as you know.

And `{0}, {1}, {2}` is the order of format, and you can skip the order as `{}, {}, {}`, in this case var replace continuously. (as `{0}, {1}, {2}`)

and you can study more information about python format 
 in this [site](https://pyformat.info/)

---

In python 3.6 and above, you will understand easily.

It is `f-string`

```
print (f"The sum of {num1} and {num2} is {sum}")
```

and `.format` work as replace. as below

```
print ('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format (num1,num2,sum))

>>> The sum of {value of num1} and {value of num2} is {value of sum}
```

`0`, `1`, `2` can change order

```
print ('The sum of {2} and {1} is {0}'.format (sum, num1, num2))

>>> The sum of {value of num2} and {value of num1} is {value of sum}
```

Comment: The correct name for your “format string” is called Literal String Interpolation or more commonly referred to, the f-string. You might want to take a note in your answer, in place of the “format string”. I have also changed 3.7 to 3.6 in your answer since the f-string is introduced in python 3.6. See here for more details pep 0498: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ . Ps. There’s also the %-formatting style.

Comment: And you should also take some notes of the comment made by PRMoureu since the OP asked to explain what `str.format` is and how it works, in which you hadn’t explain it yet.

Comment: Thanks guys for solving my problem. It helps me solve the prob now. Since I am a beginner i thought the best place to get answer would be here in stackoverflow.